# Delete files using java

Tags: java, file

In my `java` application, I'm using `FilenameFilter` to get `zip` files in given directory. My directory structure is looks like below.

```
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir1
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir2
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir3
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir4
```

`zip` files are in `dir` folders. I'm giving only `D\\:\\MyFiles\\data` to my program and it find folders start with `dir` using `FilenameFilter` and then find files ends with `zip` on `dir` folders.

Inside a `for loop` I'm creating `new File` objects for each `zip` files and call `delete()` to delete them, but they aren't deleted.

I have printed file path using `getPath()` method; output is looks like below.

```
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir1\a.zip
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir1\b.zip
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir2\b1.zip
D\:\MyFiles\data\dir3\d.zip
```

Then I manually created a `File` object as `File f = new File("D/:/MyFiles/data/dir1/a.zip")` and try to delete. It succeeded.

How can I delete files? How can I give the correct path?

**UPDATES**

This is the code what I'm using:

```
// this contains folders start with 'dir' in 'D:\MyFiles\data\'
    Vector<String> dirList = utl.identifyDir(conf);

File dir;
for (int i = 0; i < dirList.size(); i++) {

// in my properties file ITEM_FOLDER is written as ITEM_FOLDER=D\:\\MyFiles\\data
//  LOG.fine(conf.readConfig(Configuration.ITEM_FOLDER)); returns D:\MyFiles\data

    dir = new File(conf.readConfig(Configuration.ITEM_FOLDER)
            + File.separator + dirList.get(i));

    // this contains all the files ends with 'zip' in 'dir' folders in 'D:\MyFiles\data\'
    Vector<String> zipFiles = utl.identifyZipFiles(dir);

    for (int x = 0; x < zipFiles.size(); x++) {

        /* delete */

        File sourcePath = new File(
                conf.readConfig(Configuration.ITEM_FOLDER)
                        + File.separator + dirList.get(i)
                        + File.separator + zipFiles.get(x));

            boolean sp = sourcePath.delete();

            LOG.fine("sourcePath : " + sourcePath.getPath() + " : "
                    + sp);

                // one of LOG prints is D:\MyFiles\data\dir3\d.zip : false



    }
}
```

Comment: It was succeeded? So it worked? What did you try to delete the file? I also see `D/:/MyFiles`, that can't be right. You didn't use `D:/MyFiles`?

Comment: Hm, is it correct that path looks like "D\:\MyFiles..." instead of "D:\MyFiles..."?

Comment: Do you check what the delete() returns?

Comment: Which exception did you get?

Comment: @Joetjah I'm stored parent path in java `properties` file. i'm choosing it using `fileChooser`. in my properties file, it written as `D\:\\MyFiles\\data`. in my programe, i'm reading properties file and get that path.

Comment: @ellak `delete()` returns `false`

Comment: the qn is not right for sure

Comment: @FestusTamakloe no exceptions

Comment: @Bishan the file that your create with you java code do you put it in the same folder as the others?

Comment: @FestusTamakloe i'm not creating files. i'm only create File objetcs.

Comment: Wait, so you manually created a new File and tried to delete that, and it worked? I notice that there you use `D/:/`, and getPath() gives ` D\:\ ` .

Comment: @Joetjah no. i'm not created a file. i'm only created a file object by givin existing file path as `File f = new File("D/:/MyFiles/data/dir1/a.zip")`. and it worked.

Comment: Not only that, all slashes are from \ instead of /. Don't know if it'll make any difference...

Comment: Yes, that worked. When using `getPath`, it's different. When you create a File-object all slashes are /. When you use FilePath, all slashes are \. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @Joetjah i think it is the issue. :( coze `File f = new File("D/:/MyFiles/data/dir1/a.zip")` worked.

Comment: post updated with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your update, I think there are 2 possible things going on here.

1. You've still got something open in your application. You don't happen to use a FileInputStream or anything?
2. Another process is keeping the .zip busy. Did you open that file? Try closing the explorer window or something like that.

EDIT: A checklist from an other user:

- Check that you've got the path correct, e.g. what does `file.exists()` return?
- Check that you've got permission to delete the file as the user running your application
- Check that you haven't got an open handle to the file within your code (e.g. have you just read from it and not closed the input stream?)
- Check that you don't have the file opened in a desktop app

Comment: There is a `FileInputStream` and i forgot to close it. now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new File-object to test, something is different then when you use `getPath`. Notice how all the slashes in the pathname are \ instead of /.

Comment: i'm not using `getPath` to create File object. it's only use for printing to find the issue.

Comment: Then post some of your code. What does the for-loop look like? Everybody is just guessing out here because we don't know how it looks like.